# How to create pattern in input in html allowing only number and two special character?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Here is my code. From this code I can create pattern which allow only number and two special character # and *. But I can't control space. I need to restricted space usage in this input.

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="^[0-9#* ]+$" >
```

Comment: Do you know anything about Regex? It looks like your question is about Regex, not JavaScript either HTML.

Comment: ya not too much but little bit.

Comment: i m at learning stage

Comment: Play with your pattern here: https://regex101.com/. In the left tab, select JavaScript as flavor. In order to forbid spaces, remove the space in the pattern.

Comment: Do you want to restrict user to use space in input? If yes then just need to remove space from you pattern `<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="^[0-9#*]+$" >`

Comment: thank you so much rahul verma.

Comment: and what about if i want to compare particular string through pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this](https://regex101.com/r/aS9xT0/29) regex for your requirement, you need to use

```
"^[0-9#*]+$"
```

Comment: what about if i want to compare particular string through pattern? for example *99#

Comment: Use `pattern="\*99#"`.

Comment: but what about two? i need to compare two option.